# Are there any options for learning chess from people on the Internet?

Tags: online-chess, coach

I'm not sure if I remember correctly, but I think there used to be an option on Chess.com for learning chess from people on the Net (I'm not referring to the Lessons or Tactics or Drills options). I think the option was named 'Coaches', though I might be mistaken.

So was there ever such an option on Chess.com? It doesn't seem to be there, now (I use the Chess.com **app**, though. Maybe the app doesn't have the option?). I'd like some information from fellow users of Chess.com.

If such an option is not available on Chess.com (or the app), could someone name a site where I can find people who can teach chess over the Net?

Comment: I know similar function from Chessbase, "Let's Check".

Comment: What is your level? If possible I'd recommend to join a chess club, which IMO for a beginner is more fun and efficient than formal teaching sessions. Apart from coaches there is plenty of other material available on the internet, particularly you can watch master players comment on games/openings, etc which can help you a lot to improve.

Comment: @user1583209 I'm sort of a beginner, (my rating on chess.com varies from 1200 to 1300, but I don't play often). Joining a chess club is a bit difficult due to lifestyle reasons, but I'll try joining one on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Why has the question been downvoted? Maybe there is something in it I need to improve? Please tell me if I've unknowingly gone against some​ rules of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a lot of coaches in different languages on https://www.chess.com/coaches and also on https://lichess.org/coach.

Comment: Thanks, @Don , does that work even on the lichess app? Thanks again (+1)!

Comment: Sorry i don't use the app

Comment: Oh, okay thanks anyway, @Don! I couldn't find the coaches option on Chess.com app, but that's maybe because it's the app! I'll check it on my laptop! Thanks!

Comment: @HarryWeasley My understanding is that these are basically lists of coaches. The actual coaching is done via skype (or similar) and perhaps using study boards in lichess (and or similar features elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

We recommend [Alberto Chueca](https://www.albertochueca.com), one of the best chess coaches in the world. His students are getting great results and his price is very economical.

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Please note that we have some [rules](/help/promotion) regarding promotion; it's best if you [edit] your answer to indicate whether you're a friend, relative, or student of this coach.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Chess Club is a subscription-based chess server. They have a list of accredited coaches ([Coaches](https://store.chessclub.com/teachers)) who you can book for online lessons (shared board and talk via Skype). Fees vary from $50-$100 for grandmasters down to $20-$30 for FMs or IMs. They also tend to be lower for coaches in poorer countries.

Apart from being a member for many years I have no commercial connection with ICC. I've never actually used the services of a coach but the system seems to work well enough.